# gulp-istanbul, isparta and ES6 test coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, istanbul, isparta

I'm building a REST API in which I have many unit tests.

I need now to have some information about them, like code coverage.

I've read many articles dealing with [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) and [Isparta](https://github.com/douglasduteil/isparta), and their ability to run test coverage (with mocha's help) of ES6 code ([this article](https://onsen.io/blog/mocha-chaijs-unit-test-coverage-es6/)) so I wanted to use them.

I'm working with NodeJS 0.12.7, and I use Babel transpiler to convert my ES6 code to ES5.

I use gulp tasks like following:

```
/* Unit test task */
gulp.task('pre-test', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/app/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(istanbul({
      instrumenter: isparta.Instrumenter,
      includeUntested: true
    }))
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('test:unit', ['pre-test'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/test/unit/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: 'spec'
    }))
    .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({}));
});
```

---

However, when trying to use the tools like below, I have these kinds of errors:

```
C:\projects\nodejs\project\src\test\unit\core\TestConfReader.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import ConfReade
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

It means that istanbul isn't able to recognize ES6 code. I'm probably missing something right there.

**So my question is:**

How can I unit tests and apply test coverage on my ES6 code (and not on the ES5 code, that has many generated code like a try/catch in each class constructor) with Node 0.12.7?

Answer (score 0):

First install 'babel' from npm.

Then add `require('babel/register');` at the beginning of your gulpfile.